# is there a database/wiki of browser/platform quirks and inconsistencies?

Tags: html, css

Often, even with a reset stylesheet, things will show up a little different from browser to browser, or on different platforms (especially with mobile).

I'm just wondering if there is any place that really breaks down quirks and differences between different browsers and platforms.

I've seen this for IE6.. which is great, but not the whole story! I've also seen a lot of lists of what is or isn't supported, but I've had less luck finding a place that lays out all the little niggly differences people have found.

Answer (score 1):

For particular HTML, CSS and JavaScript features, the [SitePoint Reference](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css) is very good.

Another similar resource is [Quirksmode.org](http://quirksmode.org/), "the prime source for browser compatibility information on the Internet".